# ValueError: Key() must have an even number of positional arguments. Python App Engine NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

ValueError: Key() must have an even number of positional arguments.

When I try:

```
class MyStorage(ndb.Model):
 my_attr = ndb.StringProperty()

 my = MyStorage(parent=ndb.Key('mylist'), key_name='myattr', my_attr = 'hello')
```

What am I doing wrong?

My aim is to store a few MyStorage entities under a parent entity with key 'mylist'. I don't want to attach anything to the parent itself, and neither have I instantiated it, but from the docs I didn't get the impression that was necessary.

How do I persist MyStorage entities the way I describe above correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ndb.Key()` constructuctor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors) expects pairs of `kind` and `id` values, not one string:

```
ndb.Key(model1, id1, model2, id2, ..)
```

The pairs can be specified in different ways, or you need to provide a `urlsafe` argument (which is a websafe-base64-encoded serialized reference).

Comment: If as above the only reason I want to include a parent is for a common ancestor, is there a kind of null object I can initialise it to? Maybe: ndb.Key(Model, 'mylist')?

Comment: @user1561108: just leave out the `parent` key, I believe.